# MyPy gives error "Missing return statement" even when all cases are tested

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am getting a MyPy error "Missing return statement", even when I check for all possible cases inside a function.

For example, in the following code, MyPy is still giving me an error `"9: error: Missing return statement"`, even though `color` can only be `Color.RED`, `Color.GREEN`, or `Color.BLUE`, and I test all those cases!

```
class Color(enum.IntEnum):
    RED: int = 1
    GREEN: int = 2
    BLUE: int = 3


def test_enum(color: Color) -> str:
    if color == Color.RED:
        return "red"
    elif color == Color.GREEN:
        return "green"
    elif color == Color.BLUE:
        return "blue"
```

Comment: You didn't handle the case if `color` doesn't equal to any of those three cases. For example, `color` equals to `"hahaha you missing me"`.

Comment: There's a path through the code that doesn't return anything (i.e., if `color` is not one of the colors you're checking).  You could change the final `elif` to an unconditional `else`, or add a new `else` that throws an error or returns an error code.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. In a language like Swift, this would be perfectly valid because the Swift compiler interprets the possible options from the enum. My guess is that MyPy doesn't do that (yet) and is simply comparing string value to string value completely unaware of the enum context.

Comment: I would maybe try filing a bug on the mypy tracker/try seeing if this is already filed as a bug. Mypy has been steadily adding more and more support for enums, but perhaps this isn't a case that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @Michael0x2a https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4223

Comment: This has since been fixed in `mypy`, IMO it's time to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no question in this question - mypy indeed behaves this way at the moment. The enum support is baked in, and is preliminary and somewhat ad-hoc. The kind of checking you are looking for might be implemented in the future.

However, this code is fragile; if Color will change, it will silently break. 
Remember that Python is not a compiled language - the typechecker pass is optional, and someone else might not use it.

The right way IMO is to add `assert False` at the end. This will also silence mypy.