# Mypy throws and error 'Missing return statement', but i can't see where I'm missing it

Tags: python, python-requests, mypy

I'm trying to implement a retry function in http_requests, but I'm running into problems with a 'needed' return statement, although I cant figure out where this should be

```
def _http_request(method: _HttpMethod, url: str, **kwargs) -> Optional[requests.models.Response]:
    _body: Any = None
    _retries: Any = 3
    if "json" in kwargs:
        _body = kwargs.get("json")
    elif "data" in kwargs:
        _body = kwargs.get("data")
    elif "retries" in kwargs:
        _retries = kwargs.get("retries")
    elif "timeout" in kwargs:
        _timeout = kwargs.get("timeout")

    for _retry in range(1, _retries):
        try:
            logging.debug(f"{method.value} {url} body: {_body}")
            _response = requests.request(method.value, url, **kwargs)
            logging.debug(f"{_response.status_code} body: {_response.text}")
            return _response
        except NewConnectionError:
            logging.error("Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.")
            return None
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            logging.error("Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host.")
            return None
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            if _retry <= 3:
                logging.warning(f"Connection to Jira timed out after {_timeout}, trying to connect again({_retry} of {_retries} retries)")
            else:
                logging.error(f"Failed to connect to jira server efter {_retries}")
                return None
```

Comment: What is the full text of the error message.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149154/mypy-gives-error-missing-return-statement-even-when-all-cases-are-tested

Comment: Andy G -The error message is:  `Missing return statement _mypy(error)_`  displayed at method definition level, with no indication on where it would need a return statement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The return statements are within the for loop, but not after it, creating an inconsistency.

Add `return None` outside of (after) the for loop.

The block `if _retry <= 3:` is also inconsistent in that it does not have a return statement, but `return None` after the loop may resolve the warning.

Comment: Although I cannot comprehend why MyPy cannot see the return statements in the loop, this seems to have fixed my problem, though I don't like the way it looks, but it works. (:

Comment: If the loop were never entered then the method would not encounter a return statement. We can see that the loop will always be entered, because _retries is given the value 3, but the parser cannot (or will not) determine this.